# SharePoint search metadata is not searchable after SP3

Tags: 2007, search, managed-metadata

On a single-server farm we had the SharePoint 2007 Service Pack 3 installed without our knowledge, which seems to have affected the search and managed metadata properties negatively.

We have a number of custom metadata properties that are mapped to document and list-specific columns. We have run the SharePoint Configuration Guide post-install and run a full crawl, but still the search returns NULL (blank) for the needed metadata properties.

If we go to check them in the list, the mapping is still there and it even says "More than 1000 item" in the index, so it seems to be indexing them, but the results show otherwise.

Does anyone know what could be causing this and how to fix it?

Answer (score -1):

Why dont you reset the index and perform a full crawl.

Comment: We tried that, no go. It starts at "0 items" and goes up to "More than 1000 items" as before, but if I try to search for it, none of our custom metadata properties return anything.